# What does 'Attribute error: List object has no attribute lower' mean? Sklearn toolkit (Countvectorizer)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, countvectorizer

I have followed various tutorials using the sklearn toolkit to transform text into a vector for a machine learning model I am building. I keep getting this error with my code:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mbI3.png)

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(anon_words)

print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

print(X.toarray)
```

I think it is because my data is in a list because I've done lots of pre-processing on it?

Here is an image of the output of my text from the previous step:
[Text following pre-processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWwU2.png)

Comment: where is `lower` used in your code?

Comment: Is that the full stacktrace of the error that you get? Like Harasha said, there is no `lower` in the code you posted. If it is not the full stacktrace, please post it.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani  I have updated the post which screenshots of my error message and code. Thanks!

Comment: please add code instead of attachments